# Safe way of exposing ports to GETH?

Tags: go-ethereum, security

I am in the process of deploying a local eth node using GETH. I am using docker compose to orchestrate the process.

I was hoping to get an answer of whether I am exposing my ports safely. I'm concerned exposing 0.0.0.0, however I was having difficulty connecting to the node from localhost when I only allowed localhost.

I am running GETH with these flags:

```
  - --http
  - --http.api=eth,net,web3,engine,admin
  - --http.addr=0.0.0.0
  - --ws
  - --ws.origins=127.0.0.1
  - --ws.addr=0.0.0.0
  - --ws.api=eth,net,web3
  - --graphql
  - --authrpc.addr=127.0.0.1
  - --authrpc.jwtsecret=/root/.ethereum/jwt.hex
  - --authrpc.port=8551
  - --txlookuplimit=0
```

sudo ss -tlpn
[image]

Comment: When I set the *.addr to localhost, I am unable to access the node and get an error "Recv failure: Connection was reset" when I try to curl localhost:8545

Comment: It would be really helpfull if you would also attach out put of this command to check ports status on your machine
Linux: `sudo ss -tlpn`
Mac: `lsof -i -P | grep -i "listen"`

Comment: @Akbar30bill Thanks, I added a screenshot

Comment: To set up a private eth node you can create an SSH tunnel into the or ssh portforwarding into the machine hosting your node.

Answer (score 0):

So, The flags used for GETH are safe and reasonable. But the logic behind docker ports is exposing the 8551 port to the internet, which shouldn't be exposed. So I suggest not opening that port at all and only using it inside the docker containers to connect the consensus layer to the execution layer (Prysm and Geth)